# Image from XML to Cell

Tags: image, swift, asynchronous, uitableview

i wanted to load `ASYNC` an Image to a Cell.

my Code is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as xmlParserDatenCell

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        var test =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: daten[imagePath.row]["bildlink"]!)!)!)
        cell.bild1.image = test
        })
```

my answer from this is `nil`.

No idea to to it. :(

i searched the WEB for hrs.

EDIT:

var daten = [String:String] looks my daten.
and my parser returns this into:

daten.append(String:String)

Comment: Are you sure that `daten` is `[String: String]`? If that's true then you wouldn't access it like `daten[index][string]`, it would just be `daten[string]`. Sounds like you have an array of dictionaries, or you have an architectural problem. Without more code, my answer is all the help I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things going wrong here. When you leave the main queue for an async, you have to return to main before setting the image. Additionally, you need to debug your code to make sure at each step you're getting what you expect (i.e. Is `daten[0]["bildlink"]` actually returning an image address?)

Anyways, here's some code that should work if you're using swift 1.2 and the xml is actually returning some data.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in  // background
  var loadedImage: UIImage? //optional image, will be set if the rest succeeds
  if let link = daten[indexPath.row]["bildlink"],  // address for image
    url = NSURL(string: link),                    // .. to URL
    data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),            // .. to data
    image = UIImage(data: data) {                 // .. image from data
      loadedImage = image
  }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in  // return to main thread
    cell.bild1.image = loadedImage ?? nil  // if above successful, actually set image
  }
}
```

You should also check to make sure the cell hasn't been reused before setting the image. You can do this a whole bunch of ways, but I would add a property like `imageAddress` to save the string from `daten[0]["bildlink"]` and reference it like `if cell.imageAddress == link { cell.bild1.image = loadedImage }`

Comment: Hello, thx of the Answear, Yes it does.... 3Times ??? with an \n at the end... and your code not to be in use, (println("Hello World") does not appear.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? Can you provide additional information?

Comment: Hello, thx for answer.  Okay i had my little problem about that. my numbersOfSection wasn't set. Then your code is nice, but i get an error now. Downcast from String? to String only Unwraps Otionals; dir you mean to use"!"? at this point: if let link= self.date[0]["bildlink"] AS! (<-- Here) String, what can i do? ist actually an Sring. See my edit at start.

Comment: I updated the code based on that information, and added `indexPath.row` as the index for `daten`.

Comment: THX :D, but i get in this code a NIL when i set a breakpoint @cell.bild1.image = loadedImage ?? nil, what can i do?

Comment: If you're getting nil there it likely means a) `daten[indexPath.row]["bildlink"]` doesn't have any data, b) it does have data, but it's not an address that's convertible to a URL. c) the URL doesn't contain an image... d) something else... I would break on `if let link = daten...`, step through each line and see where you go wrong.

Comment: Big THX, it worked now :) i had to separate the string first. it cames a \n this little thing makes a big error.... Now i must figure out to make some sections in my tableview. with dates as headline. Like the phonebook with the alphabet.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! Please mark the answer correct if you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

To make an async web request you can use:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{
  (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  // do stuff with response, data & error here
})
```

If you're using it inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you may not end up with the same cell as you expect since it's async and cells get reused, so make sure you have the correct cell before you set the image:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

  var urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: daten[indexPath.row]["bildlink"]!)!)

  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{
    (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if let cellToUpdate = self.tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
      cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
      // need to reload the view, which won't happen otherwise since this is in an async call
      cellToUpdate.setNeedsLayout()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hello Christina :), so i has tested your code, but it crashes on var cell = SELF(<-- Here).tableView!..... with: TableViewController does not have a member named `tableView´ EDIT: I has written here right, and in my code wrong sorry... tableView it´s right ^^ (copy --> paste ^^)

Comment: Thank u Christina. Your Code, and the Code from @Andrew has helped me out. :)